# Chrome - set search bar to google.co.uk, not google.com?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

How can I force Chrome to search google.co.uk in the search bar, rather than google.com?

I have tried the following several times with no success:

- go to google.com
- click on 'Go to Google UK'
- do a search
- restart Chrome

Like I say, the above doesn't work. I've also tried resetting all Chrome's language options to UK English and restarting the browser. I am actually in the UK, and not using a proxy.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

2018 answer, pulled from [Google's docs](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop):

> 1. On your computer, open Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
> 3. Under "Search engine," click Manage search engines.
> 4. Find "Other search engines."
>
>    - **Add:** To the right of "Other search engines," click **Add**. Fill out the text fields and click **Add**.
>    - **Set as default:** To the right of the search engine, click More (3 dots) > More and then **Make default**.
>    - **Edit:** To the right of the search engine, click More (3 dots) > More and then **Edit**.
>    - **Delete:** To the right of the search engine, click More (3 dots) > More and then **Remove from list**.

So to add Google UK's search engine, the entry I used had "Google UK" as the Search engine, "google.co.uk" as the keyword, and "https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=%s" as the URL.

Answer (score 6):

If JNK's answer didn't do the trick, make sure you're using `https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%s` for the URL. So, the full procedure is:

1. Right click the URL box at the top of any Google Chrome window.
2. Click *Edit Search Engines…*
3. Click the *Add…* button.
4. Set the name to whatever you want (e.g. "Google UK").
5. Set the keyword to whatever you want (e.g. "uk").
6. Set the URL to `https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%s`.
7. Click the *Add* button.
8. Click the *Make Default* button.

Comment: This suggestion no longer works due to updates in Chrome.

Comment: This worked for me today. I'm traveling in Poland and was getting google.pl results from my address bar searches. Doing this with google.com (instead of .co.uk) worked perfectly.

Comment: Above works if you change URL in step 6 to "https://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=%s"

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings (the wrench on the right)

-> Options

-> Default Search - click "Manage"

-> "Add" button at the top

-> Fill out the info, putting google.co.uk as the keyword

-> You may need to copy the URL from the default google entry.

Enjoy!

Comment: This breaks search suggestions for me. It will only show queries I've previously searched for, but no [other suggestions](https://twitter.com/axelk/status/621352271150977025).

Comment: This suggestion no longer works due to updates in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above worked for me in the latest update of Chrome (October 2018) except the following:

In Chrome under Options (the wrench) go to Default Search -> Manage 
In the new window fill in the boxes as follows:

Name: Google.XX
Keyword: Google.XX
URL: http://www.google.XX/search?q=%s 
** where XX is the specified country, in my case I used .ca for Canada

from https://ccm.net/forum/affich-14111-how-to-change-from-google-xx-to-google-com